# filter a table with 80 millions of records and no index and copy it to a new table

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres DB with 80 millions of records and no index. One of these columns, say  `d`, is a date-time.

I want to take all the records such that `d > 1/1/2018` into another table.

Which is the most efficient way to do this?

What I am currently doing:

```
Select * into new_table from big_table
where d> '1/1/2018'
```

But this is taking hours, and I have no visibility on the time that I have to wait for this query to finish.

Would it be better to create first an index on the column d and then do the select into?

An option is also to remove from my table all the records with `d < 1/1/2018`, but I am not sure that this will be faster..

Comment: How many of the rows are filtered out by the condition? If only a few rows are returned by the filter, the an index on the column might make sense.

Comment: After the filtering I expect to have in the worst case less than 10 millions rows.

Comment: Then an index might indeed help. The execution plan will show you

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name wouldn't create index require SeqScan on whole table anyway?.. If OP wants it as one time operation - just selecting as is would be faster?

Comment: In my experience I've found that it's faster to create the table as part of the select statement, rather than create it up front and then put data in it, e.g. `CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM ...`. Whether it's feasible to do in your case is another matter.